# How do I implement the 'add' FAB on the bottom right like I see in many Google web apps?

Tags: html, css, material-design, angular-material

I'm am trying to implement a FAB **on the bottom right corner** of my web app. Is manual CSS the only way to do this? I do not see any documentation for this on https://material.angularjs.org.

This is an example of what I want to implement (the bottom right red button):

[image: FAB add button on bottom right]

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/fabSpeedDial

Comment: @SLaks I want to place it specifically on the bottom right of the page. I just found out I can add a `class` `md-fab-bottom-right` to the button which solved my problem. I'll post the answer now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just found out the answer:

```
<md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right" aria-label="Add a category">
  <md-icon>add</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

I had to add a classname of `md-fab-bottom-right`.

Answer (score 10):

The main CSS rule is "right"; in order to add to Luis's answer, add this rule to the CSS:

```
.md-fab-bottom-right{
    position: fixed !important;
    right: 15px; /* Add this and change value to set the margin you want */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To improve your question: if you have problems with the button's position add this to your css:

```
.md-fab-bottom-right{
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

This way, the button will be fixed even if the user do scroll